# How do we measure the total amount of variation in height of Earth's topography?

Tags: geomorphology

Could it be measured by taking the Laplacian over all tiles and then averaging it, for example?

(this question can be relevant for both surface topography and ocean bathymetry).

I think measuring it relative to Earth's geopotential would be fine.

Comment: I think this question could get a pretty good answer at [GIS.SE].  I also think there is not really one answer.  There are many ways and the most appropriate one depends on the problem you are trying to solve.  *What do you want to find out?*

Comment: Also, what are you measuring it relative to? As a geophysicist, I would choose a gravitational equi-potential, but others might choose a geoid (which one?) or something else.

Comment: @gerrit - It's a geodesy question, which is equally well suited to either here or the GIS stackexchange, i.m.o.

Comment: What do you mean by "tiles"? Also, what do you want to know: the average variation, the peak-to-peak variation, the maximum?

Comment: What do you mean by "variation"? Statistical variance or something else?